# An infinite Set

Tags: real-analysis

I just came across a definition of infinite sets as follows "A set is infinite if it can be placed in one-to-one correspondence with a subset of itself." It then proceeds to say that the set of rational numbers is countable infinite.

Consider the following subset of rational numbers: 
$X=\{1\}$ which is a proper subset of the rational numbers. Does the one-one correspondence arise because  $1$ can be expressed as  countably infinite ways as fractions where the numerator and denominator are the same?

Comment: The definition doesn't mean "with any proper subset." Just with some subset. So no, the rational numbers cannot be put in 1-1 correspondence with $\{1\}$.

Comment: An aside: technically, this is the definition of [Dedekind infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set). Assuming the axiom of choice, this is equivalent to just being infinite, but without choice you can have infinite (that is, non-finite) sets which are not Dedekind infinite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no one to one correspondence between the rationals and the set $\{1\}$.

The (almost correct) definition you quote says

> with **a** subset of itself

not

> with **every** subset of itself

You can find a one to one correspondence between the set of rationals and the subset of integers, or even with the subset "all the rationals except $1$".

The definition is only almost correct because, as @coffemath comments, the subset must be a proper subset - not the whole thing.

Comment: A correcter definition would mention 1-1 correspondence with a *proper* subset of itself. :-)

Comment: I see- because then every set would always be countably infinite..

Comment: @coffeemath Edited with your comment thanks.